# Путь к файлу по pid_t

Tags: c, процесс, linux

У меня есть pid_t процесса, и есть необходимость получить путь к файлу, который выполняется в этом процессе. Как это можно сделать средствами c?

Comment: Может быть не совсем понимаю, что Вы хотите, но если что-то такое:

    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ls -l /proc/1683/exe 
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 avp avp 0 Dec 13 07:46 /proc/1683/exe -> /bin/bash
    avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ 


То, посмотрите `man proc` и `man 2 stat` `man 3 readlink` (как @KoVadim указал) (это для вытаскивания пути в Си программе).

Answer (score 3):

можно сделать практически в одну строку. Система создает для всех запущенных процессов симлинк на бинарник. Его можно найти в каталоге `/proc/$PID$/exe`. Осталось дело за малым - прочитать этот симлинк и узнать инфу о нем. Для этого есть функция [readlink](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) (там есть пример использования). каталог `/proc/$PID$/` можно использовать и для получения другой информации - списка открытых файлов, окружения.

Предупреждение:

- прочитанный путь может быть не всега тем, что ожидается.
- в случае скриптов, получите путь к интерпретатору. используйте cmdline к примеру.
- в некоторые каталоги нужно осторожно заходить - может прав не хватить.